# Packagist server without Solr?

Tags: php, solr, composer-php, packagist

We want to setup a private Packagist server (https://packagist.org/, https://github.com/composer/packagist) in our infrastructure.

We consider running Solr overhead as we will not have that have many packages. The Packagist documentation says that Solr is required by the search index. I couldn't find information about whether the search index is a mandatory feature, or whether I can run Packagist without it.

Any chance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You almost certainly just want to setup satis not a clone of the packagist website https://github.com/composer/satis

Comment: Thanks Danack! This looks promising :) I'll have a look

Answer (score 0):

Yep, solr is completely optional, you need it only if you need search functionality.